# How to declare app-wide custom font for all text

Tags: fonts, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I already have a custom font put into my `app/resources/<platform>/fonts` folders and have used it on several UI elements across my app, but is there a way to declare this the default font for text across the whole app? 
I would assume that this would be done in `tiapp.xml` maybe? Otherwise the only way I could think of achieving this is setting the font for every element individually in the `app.tss`, but that quickly becomes tedious and an element could be skipped. I'm sure there has to be a better solution out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSS files are best place to apply custom fonts on app wide text/labels/buttons etc.

This is how you can you can do it:

**app.tss**

```
"Label" :   {
    font : {
        fontFamily : 'custom_font_1'  // app->assets->fonts folder
    }
}


".custom_font" :   {
    font : {
        fontFamily : 'custom_font_file'  // app->assets->fonts folder
    }
}
```

---

**ViewName.xml**

```
<Label class="custom_font" text="Hello there!" color="black" />
<Label class="view-class" text="Hello there!" color="blue" />
<Label text="Hello there!" color="red" />
```

---

**ViewName.tss**

```
".view-class" :   {
    font : {
        fontFamily : 'another_font'  // app->assets->fonts folder
    }
}
```

In this example, we have defined different fonts at **3** places. **2** fonts in **app.tss** file, and **1** font in **ViewName.tss** file.

In **ViewName.xml** file:

- 1st Label will use **custom_font** class from **app.tss**
- 2nd Label will use **view-class** class from its own **ViewName.tss**
- 3rd Label will use **default Label font** from **app.tss**

So, I have presented you different ways to suit every app's requirements. Your particular case is Label 3rd.

Just like you have used **Label** in **app.tss**, you can use any Titanium text-type element like TextField, TextArea, Button, etc.

Refer more here: [Global Styling & Themes in Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes)

Comment: That's currently what I do have implemented. Was hoping for more of a 'catch-all' case, but thank you nevertheless.

Comment: That's what 3rd Label in XML is for. No need to define any class on 3rd Label and it will pick up default styling from app.tss using "Label" style as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do need to define it in app.tss across all object types you want to style. The only way, I think.